# csv file with variable columns

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I have a CSV file that doesn't have a fixed number of columns, like this:

```
  col1,col2,col3,col4,col5    
  val1,val2,val3,val4,val5 
  column1,column2,column3
  value1,value2,value3
```

Is there any way to read this kind of CSV file with Spring Batch?

I tried to do this:

```
<!-- Read a csv file -->
<property name="resource" value="classpath:file.csv" />

<property name="lineMapper">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
        <!-- split it -->
        <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="names"
                    value="col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,column1,column2,column3" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="fieldSetMapper">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="myBean" />
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>
</property>
```

But the result was this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4kXL.png

Comment: It's simpler to write custom Reader

Comment: can i use super csv with spring batch to costum my reader ??

Comment: It's better to try. I don't have exact answer (in opposite case I would posted the answer). All you need is to implement just one interface. See http://www.dineshonjava.com/2014/02/spring-batch-itemreader-itemwriter.html place your own logic of reading custom files in the read method. You can see how it's done in the FlatFileItemReader

Comment: okey thank you so much